# How to create a new solution using Roslyn CTP

Tags: c#, roslyn

I would like to create a solution (.sln) file using the Roslyn CTP, and then add some new projects to the solution.  Is this possible with the current CTP, and if so, can you provide a short code snippet to show how this can be done?

Comment: What is your question exactly?  You can modify the solution by hand if you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not supported in the current CTP. You can load existing solutions, but we don't currently support creating solution files, or adding and removing projects from existing solutions.

Comment: I'd really love to see this in the next CTP! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new solution just by checking the .sln and .csproj syntax (it's xml).
Then you can easily load them. The current CTP does not write new solutions nor projects, but it works fine with new documents.